# How to solve DataConversion Warning with MinMax normalization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, minmax

Can anybody tell me how i can remove the below warning? I want to normalize a set of integer values by min-max normalization technique but i am getting this warning and don't know how to solve it? (X is a column of integer values starting from 0 to 127)

Here is the code:

```
X = df.iloc[:,0]
mms = MinMaxScaler()
a=X.reshape(-1, 1)
b=mms.fit_transform(a)
sns.set(color_codes=True)
np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, "distributions")))
ax=sns.distplot(b);
ax.set(xlabel='frequency', ylabel='Probability')
plt.show()
```

And here is the warning:

```
DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by MinMaxScaler. warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)
```

Comment: If you want to scale integers, there is nothing you can do. Either you accept this auto-cast, or do it yourself earlier (either when reading in, or using array.astype()). The latter will have no warning then, but it results in the same behaviour.

Comment: @sascha can you clarify what you mean by using array.astype()? Where should i add this change?

Comment: Did you consider googling the numpy docs with astype()? It's just some call to change the type.

Answer (score 2):

`MinMaxScaler()` works using float numbers, so it will automatically convert your `np.array` of type `np.int` to `np.float` and inform you about it. If you don't want to see this warning, do the conversion explicitly beforehand:

```
b = mms.fit_transform(a.astype(np.float))
```